# Hyperref associates equation's label to item

Tags: hyperref

I have a script that fixes references to equations called by `\ref` command, changing it in `\eqref` command. It also fixes reference to other LaTeX objetcs from `\eqref{LABEL}` or `(\ref{LABEL})` into `\ref{LABEL}`. Here some examples:

- `eq.~\ref{eq:1}` --> `eq.~\eqref{eq:1}`
- `figure~(\ref{fig:1})` --> `figure~\ref{fig:1}`

I make it by looking at the `.aux` file (using `hyperref` package). For references to equations I have this kind of string in the `.aux` file:

```
\newlabel{eq2}{{2}{1}{Section title}{equation.1.2}{}}
```

where the label `eq2` is associated to the string `equation.1.2`. So I know it's an equation' label.

Now, I find a bug into this method. This is a MWE:

```latex
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}

\section{Section title}
Some text
\begin{enumerate}
\item[(i)] Some text
\begin{equation}
x+y=z
\label{eq1}
\end{equation}
\end{enumerate}
\begin{equation}
\label{eq2}
  x+y=z
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

Where in the `.aux` file I have:

```
\newlabel{eq1}{{1}{1}{Section title}{Item.1}{}}
\newlabel{eq2}{{2}{1}{Section title}{equation.1.2}{}}
```

As you can see the label `eq1` it's not associated to the string `equation*`. It happens when I provide the optional argument to the `\item` command.

Can this be fixed?

Another solution could be making every numbered displaymath `\label` print something in the `.aux` file or in a separate file, but I have no idea how to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a bug / deficiency in the hyperref patches. It sets at the begin of the \item command a boolean to true but it isn't set back to false if the optional argument is used.

You can try this:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{xpatch}
\makeatletter
\xpatchcmd\@item{\ignorespaces}{\@hyper@itemfalse\ignorespaces}{}{\fail}
\makeatother

\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}

\section{Section title}
Some text
\begin{enumerate}
\item[(i)] Some text
\begin{equation}
x+y=z
\label{eq1}
\end{equation}
\end{enumerate}
\begin{equation}
\label{eq2}
  x+y=z
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks! This works for the MWE. I'll test it for any side effects.

Comment: I updated my question because I encontered an opposite problem that it's not fixed by the solution you proposed.

Comment: Don't update questions like this, ask a new question.

Comment: Ok,  sorry. I thought it was an issue the same question.

Comment: I removed the update and asked a new question: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/586884/33634