# Hyperref associates item's label to equation

Tags: hyperref

This question is related to this one: [Hyperref associates equation's label to item](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/586551/33634).

I have a script that fixes references to equations called by `\ref` command, changing it in `\eqref` command. It also fixes reference to other LaTeX objetcs from `\eqref{LABEL}` or `(\ref{LABEL})` into `\ref{LABEL}`. Here some examples:

- `eq.~\ref{eq:1}` --> `eq.~\eqref{eq:1}`
- `figure~(\ref{fig:1})` --> `figure~\ref{fig:1}`

I make it by looking at the `.aux` file (using `hyperref` package). For references to equations I have this kind of string in the `.aux` file:

```
\newlabel{eq2}{{2}{1}{Section title}{equation.1.2}{}}
```

I find some bugs into this method. This is a MWE:

```latex
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}

\section{Section title}
Some text
\begin{enumerate}
\item Some text
\begin{equation}
x+y=z
\end{equation}
Some text\label{item1}
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

In this case I have the string:

```
\newlabel{item1}{{1}{1}{Section title}{equation.1.1}{}}
```

In the `.aux` file but the label `item1` does not refer an equation.

Can this be fixed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This described in the documentation in section 5.3. By default anchornames are globally set.

You can use the option `localanchorname`  to get local anchors:

```
\hypersetup{localanchorname=true}
```

### Edit

As mentioned in the comment, `localanchorname` is deprecated. The name of an anchor (stored in `\@currentHref`) can also be set or used by other packages and code and it is then problematic if it is unclear if that is a global or local command and if it can escape a group or not. When using `\MakeLinkTarget` or the new PDF management `\@currentHref` is always set globally.

As alternative it is now possible to store additional properties in the auxfile. So you could add an extra label:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\pagestyle{empty}
\AddToHookWithArguments{label}{\RecordProperties{#1-extra}{target,counter}}
\begin{document}

\section{Section title}
Some text
\begin{enumerate}
\item Some text
\begin{equation}
x+y=z
\end{equation}
Some text\label{item1}
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

This would store in the aux-file:

```
\new@label@record{item1-extra}{{target}{equation.1.1}{counter}{enumi}}
\newlabel{item1}{{1}{1}{Section title}{equation.1.1}{}}
```

and so allow you to infer that `item1` with target `equation.1.1` is related to the (enumerate) counter `enumi`.

Comment: I noticed, in section 7.4, that this option is now deprecated. I only use it to make the test I described in my question and I don't keep the string in the document. Do you see some problem with this?

Comment: @GabrieleNicolardi I added an edit.